# Can't open Monodevelop with unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I can't open MonoDevelop when I double-click on a script absolutely nothing happens, nothing shows up on the taskbar or in the task manager, I looked up all the processes in the task manager put I can't find any processes for MonoDevelop. I tried deleting MonoDevelop folder on the Unity installation folder and reinstalled unity which automatically reinstalled MonoDevelop but still, MonoDevelop won't launch. I also tried to uninstall unity itself and reinstall, but still, MonoDevelop won't open. I made sure that Monodevelop (Built-in) is selected from external tools on unity, but no luck.

I know I can use Visual Studio and it's working but I really got used to MonoDevelop and I can't get my head around visual studio.

Please help. what can I do?

Comment: Are you sure you have specifiec MonoDevelop in the preferences ? [See this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1087722/getting-back-to-monodevelop-ide-from-visual-studio.html)

Comment: Yes 100% sure it's set to MonoDevelop, I even tried to launch MonoDeveop from the installation folder and it didn't launch

Answer (score 1):

Go into into task manager, and kill any background processes related to Monodevelop. If you cannot see background processes press more details at the bottom left of the task manager, and they'll show up. If that doesn't do it you can also try sync Monodevelop project from the assets menu up top. Also, make sure Monodevelop is selected as your external script editor under edit >> preferences >> external tools. If those three options don't fix the issue I usually just restart and when I get back up click sync Monodevelop before attempting to open a script.